# What are the roles of "such" and "that" in the following sentence?

Tags: syntax, parsing

"For every number a not equal to 0, there exists a number b such that ab = 1."

I am aware of a [related post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/415188/the-usage-of-such-that) on the use of "such that", I am not sure how the explanations there fit in to the use of "such that" in the above sentence.

Comment: In mathematics, “such that ...” means “for which the following property holds: ...”

Answer (score 0):

This is consistent with the following definition of **such** from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/such)

> 2. such — as/that Of the type about to be mentioned.
>    *the wound was such that I had to have stitches*

The "type about to be mentioned" is numbers that fit the criteria "ab = 1"

Comment: I don't see why Lexico explains the use of "such" in my sentence. Lexico lists "such" as a determiner, a predeterminer, or a pronoun. If "such" is a determiner or a predeterminer, then what is the corresponding noun/pronoun in the sentence? If "such" is a pronoun, what is "such" referring to? Every example in Lexico involving "such that" is of the form "... is/was such that...", a pattern that my sentence does not fit into.

Comment: The noun is a condition that `b` fits. I added one of the example sentences that is kind of similar outside the mathematical context.

Comment: This isn't an explanation; it's a translation. And it's correct. What would count as an "explanation"? A bunch of logical formulae? A history of the [_so/such ... that `S`_ construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/590888/15299)?